# Is it possible to find the largest number in a file using Vim regex?

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file of the following format:

```
warning-some txt
path_to_file, <line_number>
method name
```

The file may have more than 10,000 lines, all following the same format as above.

How can I use Vim regex to find the largest `<line_number>`? (Knowing that I can determine how big of an array I need to allocate.)

Comment: I don't believe your going to have much luck with a regex alone. Regex is a pattern search and replace tool, not a logical comparison tool.

Comment: @Jason, makes perfect sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use regular expressions to determine a maximum number. They are simply not powerful enough (because a regex has only limited memory). What you can do is simple shell magic:

```
grep '^path_to_file' | sed -e 's/^path_to_file, /' | sort -n | tail -n 1
```

By selecting a region and using the `!` command in `vim`, you can pipe your buffer through the command to achieve the effect in `vim`.

Answer (score 2):

There is an elegant way of finding the largest number in that file
by means of only Vim. The command

```
:sort!n/^path/
```

moves all of the lines in file that start with `path` above the
current first line, and orders them by the first decimal number
in a line, from the largest number to the smallest one.

If the path you would like to filter lines by contains slashes,
it is convenient to use a character other than `/` to separate
the pattern (see `:help E146`). For example,

```
:sort!n#^path#
```

Also, when the filtering by pathnames is redundant, even simpler
command might do the job,

```
:sort!n
```

simply sorting the lines by the first number occurring in them.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to get the largest `<line number>` in your file.

if we need external command in vim anyway, why not do it in shell? e.g. the awk one-liner give you the largest:

```
 awk -F, 'NF>1{max=($2+0)>max?$2:max} END{print max}' file
```

test:

```
kent$  cat v
warning-some txt
path_to_file, 234
method name
warning-some txt
path_to_file, 888
method name
warning-some txt
path_to_file, 2
method name
warning-some txt
path_to_file, 123
method name

kent$  awk -F, 'NF>1{max=($2+0)>max?$2:max} END{print max}' v
 888
```

if you like, you certainly can invoke awk within vim..

Answer (score 0):

a macro can do most of the work and we can use a second to automatize the whole task, let us
prepare a macro that updates the maximum line number when on a /path_to_file,/ line, in, say, register @l.

```
ql$by$:let m=max([m,@"])<CR>q
```

which goes to the end of the line, backs up to the beginning of the number yanks it into
the default register (@" that is) and then updates m accordingly.

Now I wrap this one into the following commands, which you might like to wrap into another
macro for reuse

```
:let m=0
:g/path_to_file/exe "normal @l"
```

which initializes the max (not having exclusively negative line numbers in your file I hope)
and then executes the macro for all matching lines thanx to the g command.

HTH